# Can't figure out why CSS is causings only one of my pages to appear incorrectly in mobile?

Tags: css, responsive-design

All the pages on my responsive site look fine on my Galaxy S7 except my homepage and I can't figure out why.

Here's an example of a page that looks fine:
http://edge-trainer.com/kick-in-the-butt-jumpstart.php

Here's my homepage:
http://edge-trainer.com/

I'm using the same CSS. Looking at my source code, can anyone see what the problem might be?

Thank you in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your homepage is that the content-wrappers are not inside the content container.

Within your normal page you linked the dom structure is

```
<div id="content-container">
   <div class="content-wrapper>yourcontent</div>
</div>
```

whereas in your home page it is

```
<div id="content-container">
   <div class="content-wrapper>yourcontent</div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper>yourcontent</div>
<div class="content-wrapper>yourcontent</div>
<div class="content-wrapper>yourcontent</div>
```

Judging by your CSS, all of the `.content-wrappers` should be inside `#content-container`

As a sidenote, it might be worth looking into `flexbox` and relative sizing for the layout you're trying out, it might make your life a bit easier, just a suggestion ;)

Comment: Thanks Lucas! You saved me from pulling all my hair out! Your solution worked perfectly!! I'll take a look into flexbox.